# How to create an Auto Increment Sequence with mongoose library

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

how to create an auto increment sequence with prefix, for example: USR00001 etc…

Little details: language Nodejs, and library mongoose.

Thank you.

Regards,
Michele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create on collection where you can keep all your sequences and then can use `findAndUpdate` to get them incremented automatically

collection - sequences

```
[
  {
    _id: "sequence",
    "value": 100000
  }
]
```

Then you can use this query to get the latest number in your format

```
db.sample.findAndModify({
      query:{
        _id: "sequence" 
        
      },
      update: {
        $inc:{
          value:1
          
        }
      },
      fields:{
        count: {$concat: [ "USR", { $toString: "$value" } ] },
        _id: 0
     }
})
```

Output:

```
{ "value" : "USR100000" }
```

For more details you can check the official documentation of [findAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Answer (score 0):

You can read this link, This has explained the way of doing it. Not sure how you will use this with Mongoose.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm